# Не могу вставить текст из одной bookmark'и в другую

Tags: c#, .net

Есть 2 Ворд документа, оба абсолютно идентичные с одинаковым набором букмарок. Делаю так

```
for (int i = 1; i <= wordDocument.Bookmarks.Count; i++)
{
    object j = i;
    wordDocument.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref j).Range.Text = wordPattern.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref j).Range.Text.ToString();
}
```

Но, этот способ просто стирает букмарки неведомым мне образом. Помогите, как корректно скопировать текст из одной букмарки в другую?

Comment: а что показывает в отладке wordPattern.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref j).Range.Text.ToString()? у вас либо достается пустой текст, либо присваивание не срабатывает - стоит проверить, что именно идет не так.